# Have you ever heard of the word electromobilists?

Tags: technical-writing, word-choice

I have to check my company's English translations for a new product they have made. The product is an electrical wall box for charging electric cars. They wrote the following sentence:

> Ideal for classic electromobilists

I have never heard of the word electromobilists and I can not find the definition anywhere online. Although English is my native language, I did not study English and I make mistakes in English all the time. Can someone tell me if this sentence makes sense?

Comment: Is this product aimed at a particular community of enthusiasts or the general public? This will affect whether you can use weird jargon or have to be generally understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is a neologism that isn't likely to get into dictionaries yet, but we all know who an automobilist is, recognise the analogy and understand. I can't say if it makes sense in the context - the quote you gave is too short for that - but hopefully it does. The word itself sounds perfectly fine to me. I can't say I recall seeing it before, but I don't think I'd take any notice if I did because there isn't anything weird or confusing about it.

Comment: Wiktionary has [electromobile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/electromobile) and derived from that, [electromobilism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/electromobilism). So yeah, electromobilist makes sense as another derivative. Though funnily enough, when I ask google about electromobiles it comes up with images of [Mobility scooters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobility_scooter) (which is where my mind went in first instance as well).

Answer (score 4):

"Electromobilist" sounds like jargon, and the word (real or not) won't be familiar to most people. Adding "classic" only makes things worse by creating an oxymoron.

I recommend you go back to the source to figure out what they were *hoping* to communicate. The phrase is that misguided!